# ANTLR Grammar and generated code problems

Tags: c#, parsing, expression, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to create an expression parser using ANTLR
The expression will go inside an if statement so its root is a condition.

I have the following grammar, which "compiles" to parser/lexer files with no problems, however the generated code itself has some errors, essentially two "empty" if statements
i.e.
if (())

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Grammar .g file below:
    grammar Expression;

```
options {
  language=CSharp3;
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  UNARY_MIN;
}

@parser::namespace { Antlr3 }
@lexer::namespace { Antlr3 }
public parse
  :  orcond EOF -> ^(ROOT orcond)
  ;

orcond
  :  andcond ('||' andcond)*
  ;

andcond
  :  condition ('&&' condition)*
  ;

condition
  :  exp (('<' | '>' | '==' | '!=' | '<=' | '>=')^ exp)?
  ;

exp
  :  addExp
  ;

addExp
  :  mulExp (('+' | '-')^ mulExp)*
  ;

mulExp
  :  unaryExp (('*' | '/')^ unaryExp)*
  ;

unaryExp
  :  '-' atom -> ^(UNARY_MIN atom)
  |  atom
  ;

atom
  :  Number
  |  '(' parenthesisvalid ')' -> parenthesisvalid
  ;

parenthesisvalid
  :  fullobjectref
  |  orcond
  ;

fullobjectref
  :  objectref ('.' objectref)?
  ;

objectref
  :  objectname ('()' | '(' params ')' | '[' params ']')?
  ;

objectname
  :  (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z'))^ (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z') | ('0'..'9') | '_')*
  ;

params
  :  paramitem (',' paramitem)?
  ;

paramitem
  :  unaryExp
  ;

Number
  :  ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
  ;

Space 
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){Skip();}
  ;
```

Comment: Did you try to implement your grammar incrementaly? Did you try to use the ANTLRWord debugger?

Comment: Maybe this thread helps. Haven't read it, but the problem seems to be the same: http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2012-September/045161.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the range operator, `..`, inside parser rules.

Remove the parser rule `objectname` and create the lexer rule:

```
Objectname
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally it will be more neatly to use **fragment** blocks. In this case your code will be something like this:

```
Objectname  :  LETTER (LETTER  | DIGIT | '_')*;    
Number: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```